# Is it possible to have a "notification only" app, or NOT show the watch app after a notification is displayed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, watchkit

The iOS app I'm working on for a client currently only uses Apple Watch for notifications.

When a local notification fires while the user's phone is locked, it displays the notification on the phone. The user can dismiss the notification or click on one of the action buttons on it.

In either case, I want to dismiss the watch app and go back to whatever state it was in (back to the watch desktop, or springboard, or whatever it's called.) I don't want to present the UI for the watch app, since there isn't one, at least not yet. I don't know if my client is going to define a watch app UI or not.

As it is now, once the user clicks the dismiss button or an action button on the notification, the user is left with a stupid-looking placeholder watch app that simply has a button called "button" (which I added for testing.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot change this. iOS decides which device the notification is shown on and you have no control over this.

If the iPhone is locked then iOS assumes that you are using your watch and will deliver the notification to it, however if your iPhone is unlocked it tends to deliver to notification to the iPhone.

Comment: That doesn't really address my question. I understand that the system decided which device to deliver a notification to. I'm talking about the case where the system delivers the notification to the watch, and then the user taps one of the action buttons on the notification. In that situation, I want my watch app to switch to the background once the user dismisses the notification.